# rails will_paginate rendering error in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I can't render my items on view using will_paginate. I get this error

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<Enumerator:0x007fe098856378>
```

Here is my pagination on controller

```
@com = @text.comments.sorted.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 30)
```

and my view file code.

```
 <% will_paginate @com.each do |text| %>
<div class="comments"> <p class="time"><%= Time.now %></p> 
<p><%=  text.text %></p></div>
```

And the controller file is

```
def show
    @text = Microblog.find(params[:id])
    @com = @text.comments.sorted.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 2)
    @rating = (@text.up - @text.down)
  end
```

And the model file

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :text, :microblog_id
    belongs_to :microblog
    scope :sorted, order("comments.created_at DESC")
end
```

I can't find what is the problem here :(

Comment: can you post the error

Comment: I have posted the error on first line. here it is undefined method `total_pages' for #<Enumerator:0x007fe098856378>

Comment: can you put your whole action from the controller? What goes into @text?

Comment: also add comment model source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing the pagination widget (< 1 2 3 >) with the listing of your available elements. What you want is:

```
<% will_paginate @com %>
<% @com.each do |text| %>
   <div class="comments"> <p class="time"><%= Time.now %></p> 
   <p><%=  text.text %></p></div>
```

Comment: Not working. Now I get the pagination view. But it does nothing. I can't click links. Here is the screenshot.http://i.imgur.com/Lv5WjFj.png

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! used `:page => params[:page]` instead of `:page => 1`
Thanks everybody